# Animation MKAnnotation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to animate a bus, I fetch a location and I want to animate it to its new location instead of it jumping from one place to another.

I am trying to do this by using UIView.animate, I have seen other answers suggest this however it is not working for me.

```
 // Find our bus annotations
                    if annotation is UUShuttleAnnotation  {

                        let shuttleAnnotation = annotation as! UUShuttleAnnotation

                        // Update this bus
                        if shuttleAnnotation.vehicleId == ann.vehicleId {

                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                                shuttleAnnotation.coordinate = ann.coordinate
                            })

                        }

                    }
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect?

Comment: When you say "not working", what precisely is it doing? Not moving at all, or jumping? If not moving at all, have you confirmed that it's reaching the line of code you think it should (e.g. add `print` or breakpoint in there and confirm). If not moving smoothly, are you doing this from the main queue?

Comment: @Rob it is not moving at all.

Comment: So, like I said, have you confirmed that this line of code is getting reached at all via breakpoint and/or `print` statement? Are you definitely doing this on the main queue? Are you sure this shuttle annotation is the one on your map? Bottom line, this `animate(withDuration:)` of changing the `coordinate` should work fine, so there's something else going on, but there's not enough here to diagnose the problem. You might consider starting with a blank project and create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com) and figure out what's necessary to reproduce the problem in question.